# Get rectangle's coordinates in PHP

Tags: coordinates, php

I'm trying to create a script which I give the center of a rectangle (in coordinates) and the preferred width and height (in metres) and return me the coordinates of four angles.

Any idea about the implementation?

[image: example IMAGE]

Comment: 2D straight-line distances, or great circle arcs?

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that your 'rectangle' is in 2D, and not wrapped around the earth.

Suppose you have the Center at `x` and `y`.
And your Height & Width are `h` & `w`.

In that case, simple arithmetic will give you:

`min_x=x-(w/2)`

`min_y=y-(h/2)`

`max_x=x+(w/2)`

`max_y=y+(h/2)`

These four values will give you the four coordinates.